# Update the Geometry of a Graphic in a FeatureLayer locally

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am using the ArcGIS JS API 4.3.  I am creating a Webmap with a FeatureLayer using a the Service URL from my ArcGIS Online account.  I would like to move the Graphics in the FeatureLayer and have the Webmap update.

I am able to achieve this either by:

1. Using the applyEdits function (sends edit to the server).
2. Updating the feature in the FeatureLayer on the server, removing and reading the FeatureLayer in the JS client.

I have the position information in my JS client and would like to simply update the Geometry of the Graphic.  I have tried to use queryFeatures, find the Graphic and update the geometry, but the view does not update.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you create a sample or jsfiddle.. or simply if you can add your current code here that will me more convenient to help you.